# Passing parameters between cells in a Jupyter Noteboook

Tags: python, parameters, sas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How would one pass a parameter from a Python Cell to a SAS Cell in a `Jupyter Notebook`?

I found the documentation to be rather vague in this area.

One possible way seems to be using the SOS Kernel to create a parent cell with sub cells; seems the parent cell would have context. I do prefer a methodology that does not require another kernel to accomplish the task of passing the parameter.